# C++ Returning a value of an array from function won't work and resets to 0 every time its ran

Tags: c++, max, return-value

I am trying to find greatest number entered, and then display it to the user.
So once the user enters several numbers, program calls function that will find it and then return it. Unfortunately every time I run it, the number resets to zero even after the function has worked successfully. What do I do wrong?

Visual Studio mentions this: *Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'gromax' is being used without being initialized.*

```
int largestGroup(int groupsize[], int theValue)                         
{                                                           
    int gromax=groupsize[0];                                

    for (int i=1;i<9;i++){
        if(groupsize[i] > gromax){
            gromax=groupsize[i];
        }
    }

    return gromax;                                                                                      
}

int main()
{

int groupsize[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int gromax = groupsize[0];
char newentry='n';  

do{                                     

    cin >> groupsize[i];

    cout << string(60, '\n');
    cout << "Would you like to enter another questionare? Enter either 'y' or 'n': " << endl;
    cin >> newentry;

    cin.ignore();                                           


}while((newentry =='y') || (newentry=='Y'));                    

        largestGroup(groupsize, i);

        cout << "Number of customers in largest group today was " << gromax << endl;
```

Comment: have you used a debugger? Why do you believe the function has worked successfully but resets to zero?

Comment: Yeah I have used a debbuger. I know that function works as I can see it "hodling" the maximum value in "gromax". Once I move into the next step(from the function back to int main), it resets to 0.

Comment: It would help if you showed the real code. It's easy enough to paste the entire program here. Why won't you do that? Do you want to know what's wrong with the program that you are running, or what's wrong with the other thing you posted here?

Comment: do you think the fact you never use the return value from the function might have anything to do with it?

Comment: @Kate: He appears to think that the return statement works based on the variable name somehow.

Comment: What is the purpose of the theValue parameter? Where is the i you use in main declared? Please show an entire program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't use the return value. Try:

```
gromax = largestGroup(groupsize, 1);
```

Comment: This has actually worked! Thank you so my friend.

Answer (score 3):

Insert in the very beginning of main

```
int i = 0;
```

and inside the loop increase it as for example

```
cin >> groupsize[i++];
```

Change this

```
largestGroup(groupsize, i);
```

statement to

```
int gromax = largestGroup(groupsize, i);
```

And remove statement

```
int gromax = groupsize[0];
```

Also you shall check in the loop that you are not trying to acces a memory beyond the array.

And function largestGroup is wrong.

Comment: Already have int i and i++, I just removed it from the code pasted here. Thank you :)

Comment: @noob You might, but we don't. I respectfully suggest that you read your own question and ask yourself whether or not it would help us if we could see the same code that you are looking at.

Answer (score 2):

```
int largestGroup(int groupsize[], int theValue)                         
{                                                           
    int gromax=groupsize[0];
```

This declares a function that - despite appearances - actually takes an array and an integer (inherited from C, arrays can decay to pointers as necessary, and it's deemed necessary when someone tries to pass them to functions).

Then, it declares a private local variable, gromax. This value, think of it as largestGroup::gromax, exists only for the life time of each individual call to the function. The last line of the function is then paramount.

```
    return gromax;
}
```

This pushes the "gromax" into whatever CPU register/location return values are stored. It will live there until something else uses the value.

The language does *not* automatically transfer the value anywhere, even if your calling function has a variable of the same name.

So, the bug in your code is this:

```
largestGroup(groupsize, i);
```

You call the function, and you never capture the return value.

```
gromax = largestGroup(groupsize, i);
```

would capture the value.

Be aware that arrays are passed by address/pointer (live demo: http://ideone.com/DTkbFn)

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int groups[5], int x)
{
    x = 3;
    groups[x] = 999;
}

int main()
{
    int groups[5] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int x = 10;

    std::cout << "before: x = " << x << ", groups[3] = " << groups[x] << '\n';

    f(groups, x);

    std::cout << "after: x = " << x << ", groups[3] = " << groups[x] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

When you pass an array, you are actually passing by pointer, so normal "pass by value" behavior does not apply.

```
int largestGroup(int groupsize[], int thevalue)
```

is actually equivalent to

```
int largestGroup(int* groupsize, int theValue)
```

It is advisable to use the second syntax to avoid falling into the trap of thinking you can modify groupsize with no impact on the caller.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining. This will be very useful for the next few lines I have to code. I am still learning, this is just small project for college. Cheers!